# How to COUNT total consecutive numbers of a value in a column in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column consists of 0 and 1. I need to count the total number of consecutive occurrences of 1.

```
Column
  0
  0
  1
  1
  1
  0
  0
  0
  1
  1
  0
  1
  1
  1
```

The answer should be: 5 (5 consecutive 1's)

Comment: i am not seeing 5 consecutive ***1's*** in your post

Comment: Are you saying that you only want to count the number of 1s that follow another 1? In that case I do see 5 but am curious what the use case is

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 or the number of consecutive ones following two or more consecutive zeroes :o)

Comment: I want to calculate the total number of consecutive 1s.

Answer (score 3):

No need for VBA or a UDF:

```
 =COUNTIFS(A1:A13,1,A2:A14,1)
```

a `SUMPRODUCT` also works:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A13=A2:A14),--(A2:A14=1))
```

In both cases, not the row offset in the ranges

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the answer 5, and the comments, I'm guessing you want to get the number of `1` following another `1`.

There's probably an easy function for that, but since I'm better with VBA...
This would check the first column (`A`) and all the way down, and return the amount of `1` that follow another `1`.

```
Sub oneFollowingOne()
Dim r As Range, total As Long
total = 0
For Each r In Range("A2", ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    If r.Value = 1 And r.Offset(-1).Value = 1 Then total = total + 1
Next r
MsgBox "Total: " & total
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Great .. You can also make a UDF(function) out of it..So that it can simply be put in a cell selecting the range as argument.